# How to handle absolute, overflow and zindex in this situation

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, overflow, absolute

I've got a dropdown component inside of several layers. The dropdown component is structured as follows:

```
<div id="label-container">
   <div id="root">
      <div id="btn" />
      <div id="menu" />
   </div>
</div>
```

The menu is position absolute and has a high z-index. Root is position relative, so the menu width conforms to the width of the dropdown.

The overall structure looks something like:

[image: html-structure]

`<label>` js the component shown above. `split-row` is each row containing two dropdowns. The parents above that are standard flex divs.

My issue is that the menu expands a parent ancestor (couple of levels up). I've tried every combination of `overflow:visible/hidden` and `position:relative` on various elements with no success.

I cannot make the menu fixed and root has to be relative to constrain the menu'a width.

How can I make the parent `overflow: hidden` but ensure the menu is still visible?

I've looked at questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513382/absolute-position-and-overflowhidden) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996856/how-to-show-bootstrap-dropdown-above-everything) but doesn't seem to have anything that works.

[image: cutoff]
[image: cutoff2]

Comment: What for does this need overflow:hidden on the parent in the first place? Can you provide a proper [mcve] please?

Comment: It needs overflow:hidden to prevent the container expanding to allow for the height of the menu, as per the second example image. @misorude to produce an example from scratch would take a reasonable amount of time, of which I don't have the luxury of in my workplace.

Comment: I'll see if I can blast one together really quickly.

Comment: Managed to fix myself when I created a minimal example! Thanks!